# Error Crystal report visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Buenas estoy migrando mi proyecto de vs 2010 a vs 2022. Solo me falta el tema de los reportes con crystal report. He instalado en un windows 11 arm64, vs 2022 y he instalado la version de crystal para vs 22. Hay compatibles la sp32 hasta la sp35. Con la sp 35 no se añade crystal a vs, con la sp 34 si pero da errores tanto para crear archivo como para ver el documento adjunto imagenes.
Donde puedo seguir buscando el problema?

Al intentar abrir un proyecto nuevo de crystal
[image: Al intentar abrir un proyecto nuevo de crystal]

Problema al ver los archivos .rpt
[image: Problema al ver los archivos .rpt]

Al abrir .rpt
[image: Al abrir .rpt]

Al intentar agregar el componente a la paleta
[image: Al intentar agregar el componente a la paleta]

Answer (score 0):

a mi también me da ese mismo error, me cansé de buscar y escribí en foros de SAP y nunca me respondieron al error, por lo que opté por trabajar con el Sp32 que hasta ahora no me da problemas. Yo estoy trabajando con un Win10 64Bit y VS2022 rev 17.